Unable to Delete or Rename Solution folder after closing Visual Studio
I am unable to Delete / Rename my Solution Folder.  This issue started happening this morning.  I don't have any program open when this error occurs.
Thank you for your assistance.

Restarting the machine does allow me to Delete the Folder.  However, once the solution  is opened in VS I am no longer able to Delete it.

I just tried deleting a New Razor Object solution folder and it worked.   What could be preventing my actual solution folder to have that error?
Thank you

I was opening different Solutions and I was able to Delete the folder for a while.  Not sure what I did different.   Thank you again for your help.

Try these two methods:

Force end the Visual Studio process: taskkill /IM devenv.exe /F
Delete temporary files and caches related to Visual Studio, usually located in the C:\Users[your username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\ directory.


Thank you for your response Dennis.
It works now all of a sudden.  I didn't change anything.

Hey, that sounds good. If you encounter a similar situation again, you can try my solution.
